# Object cannot be nil When trying to addObject

Tags: ios, objective-c

**[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil**

The problem is when trying to  execute `[_eventsArray addObject:eventModel];` error is occurred.

eventModel is nil.

How can I solve this problem ?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventsArray;
@end

@interface EventsModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString  *title;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString  *details;

@end


@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
EventsModel *eventModel ;
eventModel.title = @"Meeting";
eventModel.details = @"some description";
[_eventsArray addObject:eventModel];
}

@end

#pragma mark - Model Class
@implementation EventsModel
-(instancetype)init{
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.title = nil;
    self.details =nil;
}
return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: You haven't actually created an `eventsModel`.  You need `eventModel = [EventsModel new];`

Comment: Now its working . thanks . I forget to initialization .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EventsModel *model = [EventsModel new];

model.title = @"test";
model.details = @"Detail test";

EventsModel *model2 = [EventsModel new];

model2.title = @"test2";
model2.details = @"Detail test2";


[_eventsArray addObject:model];
[_eventsArray addObject:model2];


NSLog(@"%lu elements in array",(unsigned long)_eventsArray.count);
```

you use EventsModel *model = [EvenntsModel new]; and create object

try this code